# JSON deserialize single string

Tags: json, rest

I'm trying to get the name value from an object. I tried everything but still dont get it. Any ideas?

```
    Http http = new http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals/1');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>)
            JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        Object animal = (Object) results.get('animal');
    }
```

The value of the response:
{eats=chicken food, id=1, name=chicken, says=cluck cluck}

I'm trying to get the name value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{a=b, c=d, e=f}` format tells you that this happens to be a Map. As such, you can cast your animal as:

```
Map<String, Object> animal = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
```

From there, you can get the name value:

```
String animalName = (String)animal.get('name');
```